Read Uncommited / WITH NO LOCK on Sequelize is not working
My original code:
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 1001;
const MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 1001;
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE2 = 91;
const MAX_PAGE_SIZE2 = 91;
function calculateOffset(page, pageSize) {
    return (page - 1) * pageSize;
}

router.get('/production-data/pagination', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
        let pageSize = parseInt(req.query.pageSize) || DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
        pageSize = Math.min(pageSize, MAX_PAGE_SIZE);

        const offset = calculateOffset(page, pageSize);
        const productionData = await ProductionData.findAndCountAll({
            order: [['SaveTime', 'DESC']],
            limit: pageSize,
            offset: offset,
        });

        const nextPage = page + 1;

        res.json({
            data: productionData.rows,
            totalItems: productionData.count,
            currentPage: page,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            nextPage: nextPage,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching order data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

My original code's log:
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection has been established successfully.
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS [count] FROM [dbo].[tGapHistory] AS [ProductionData];
Executing (default): SELECT [SaveTime], [LineCode], [GAP], [PEND], [MKCNT] FROM [dbo].[tGapHistory] AS [ProductionData] ORDER BY [ProductionData].[SaveTime] DESC OFFSET 91 ROWS FETCH NEXT 91 ROWS ONLY;

Read Uncommitted attempt (for nolock):
const productionData = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
    return await ProductionData.findAndCountAll({
        order: [['SaveTime', 'DESC']],
        limit: pageSize,
        offset: offset,
        transaction: t,
        isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_UNCOMMITTED
    });
});

Read Uncommitted attempt log:
Connection has been established successfully.
Executing (7e4567741ff6d10cf0fb): BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Executing (7e4567741ff6d10cf0fb): SELECT count(*) AS [count] FROM [dbo].[tGapHistory] AS [ProductionData];
Executing (7e4567741ff6d10cf0fb): SELECT [SaveTime], [LineCode], [GAP], [PEND], [MKCNT] FROM [dbo].[tGapHistory] AS [ProductionData] ORDER BY [ProductionData].[SaveTime] DESC OFFSET 
91 ROWS FETCH NEXT 91 ROWS ONLY;
Executing (7e4567741ff6d10cf0fb): COMMIT TRANSACTION;

Hello, I was making my own project to query the data from test DB. I was suggested to implement "no-lock" when I'm reading the data.
I have attempted, but can't figure out why READ_UNCOMMITTED is not working. Based on the log, it's clearly attempting a commit transaction, making that worse than my original.
Any help would be appreciated!!

The behavior you see is unrelated to transaction isolation levels. Your transaction commits because that's the default behavior of sequelize.transaction. The managed transaction runs all statements in your callback; if any error occurs, it'll automatically roll back. Thus, if you don't want that transaction to be committed, throw an error inside the managed transaction callback.
Transaction isolation levels specify which liberties the database server can take while executing the statements in a transaction. Generally, the idea of a transaction is to isolate all changes until it is committed. However if certain guarantees aren't needed you can allow the server to ignore them to gain some more performance.
The read uncommitted level allows the server to read (e.g. with SELECT) changes by other transactions, that haven't committed yet. This is called dirty read.
As an example, if the statements are issued in order:

Transaction A: INSERT INTO posts (text) VALUES ('Post X')
Transaction B: SELECT * FROM posts
Transaction A: ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

Generally, you don't want Transaction B (2) to receive 'Post X' as a result, but with read uncommitted, you could.
It's also important to note that the server doesn't have to give you uncommitted results, just that it can. PostgreSQL for example uses MVCC and doesn't gain a performance advantage from allowing dirty reads, so the read uncommitted and read committed transaction isolation levels behave identically.
